# Optimization (Maxima and Minima)

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Question from the book additional mathematics pure and applied by JF Talbert and HH Heng...

> Given that $x + y = 8$, find the minimum value of $x + y^2$.

What I did was as follows;

- I first let $x + y² = T$
- I then expressed $T$ in terms of y by making $x = 8 -y$ from the first equation
- Then I  replaced $y$ with $8-y$ in $T$ to get $8-y+y^2 = T$
- I then differentiate $T$ wrt $y$ and I get  $-1+2y$
- But for the value to be maximum or minimum,the derivative of $T$ wrt $y$ will be $= 0$
- Hence $0 = -1 + 2y$
- Making y the subject we get $y = 1 $
- But earlier we made $x = 8 -y$, hence $x = 8 - \frac{1}{2} $
- Therefore $x = 7\frac{1}{2}$ and $y = 1$
  But the answer given by the book is $7\frac{3}{4}$ but after following the examples, am finding $\left(7\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ as my answer. Kinda confused on where am going wrong,may anyone please try and attempt it.
  Your response will be highly appreciated
  .
  .
  .
  UPDATE: I was only finding the value of y while the question said find the minumum of the whole expression x + y² . The (7.5, .5) I found was to be replaced in the expression in which we're planning to find the minimum value.

Comment: $7\frac 34 $ is the value of $x+y^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let T = $ x+y^2$
where y=8-x
$$ T=x+(8-x)^2$$
$$T= x^2-15x+64$$
Is upward opening parabola have minimum at vertex at x= 17/2
Min . T will be 31/4